# WooCommerce Measurement Price Calc - replace price range by min price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Hopefully the title is fairly self explanatory! I'm using Measurement Price Calculator (MPC) in WooCommerce here. I have added the tweak in my functions.php to alter the price display on **variable products** so that it hides the *from - to* price range and just shows *"from {lowest price}"*. I believe this is a fairly common tweak users make in WooCommerce but I'll include the code I used below for good measure as I hope it might be adaptable for MPC also.

My issue is that when using the Pricing Tables feature of MPC, it goes back to showing the price range of the table, e.g. *"€0.86 - €0.98 / sq m"*. My tweak does not catch this and I have contacted the developers Skyverge, who couldn't give me a fix but did point me to *"wc_measurement_price_calculator_get_price_html"* filter.

Has anyone here managed to this or similar when using MPC or can anyone suggest a use for the filter suggested by Skyverge?

The code I'm using for variable products is as below:

```
// Hide Price Range on Variable Products

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), 
    $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: @YvetteColomp Hello and welcome as new moderator… You should not protect this new question as it's without answers even if someone has spammed here… This way it allows people with low rank to answer… I could unprotect it, but I prefer to ask you before.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have posted two files from MPC which detail the available hooks, etc... in the product. Skyverge tell me to pay heed to _"wc_measurement_price_calculator_get_price_html"_ so can anyone discern from these files how I might filter the price range? The two files are password protected **(password: stack)** ... https://ghostbin.com/paste/hmvgbv5u and https://ghostbin.com/paste/oys6p69s. They expire in 14 days

Answer (score 0):

Without any guaranty, try this:

```
add_filter('wc_measurement_price_calculator_get_price_html', 'm_p_caculator_variable_product_prices', 10, 1 );
function m_p_caculator_variable_product_prices( $price_html ) {
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return $price_html; // Only variable products
    // Main Price
    $prices = array(  $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price_html = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $sale_price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price_html !== $saleprice ) {
        $price_html = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price_html . '</ins>';
    }

    return $price_html;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Untested.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec. The above code causes the page to only partly load... product image and title appear but no price, no side-bars, no related products, etc... I assume it's getting to the point of calling in the product price but it's hitting a problem

Comment: @ConM The problem is that I don't have your plugin and I can't look to the plugin source code and also I can't test that… I have seen in the web that this hook was used this way… I will delete that answer later then.

Comment: That's understandable, many thanks for the effort. I wouldn't delete your answer as it might serve as a base to work off. I'm going to tweak around with what you posted and see can I make something of it. There's a suffix added to all MPC prices (e.g. "/ sq m") so unless this is causing issue. Thanks again

Comment: @ConM Try to find the hook in the source code and share the code of the function that contains this hook… then I could help.

Comment: apologies for the delay. Okay, I think I see something of interest in the source. Is there an appropriate method for me to share these snippets with you as opposed to posting them here or in a public Pastebin?

Comment: @ConM You need to add a detailed update at the end of your actual question…